# Dataframe - Replace NaN to None after merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'bar'], 'b': [1, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['foo', 'baz'], 'c': [3, 4]})

final_df = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='a')

final_df.replace(np.NaN, None)
```

I am trying to merge two dataframes and the final df gives me Nan for non matched values. I tried to convert nan to None using replace method but couldn't do it.

I tried this by the suggestions in comments getting a weird result. Please help. Attaching the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will be unable to do it, because in pandas None doesn't apply for numerical dtypes as per the docs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76647057/dataframe-replace-nan-to-none-after-merge).

> In Working with missing data, we saw that pandas primarily uses NaN to represent missing data. Because NaN is a float, this forces an array of integers with any missing values to become floating point.

Even if you originally pass `None` upon creating a numerical column, it will default to `NaN` or you can consider using `pd.NA`

If you really want to use `None` despite the dtypes, then first convert the column (or dataframe):

```
final_df['c'] = final_df['c'].astype(object).replace(np.nan,None)
```

Returning:

```
     a  b     c
0  foo  1   3.0
1  bar  2  None
```

Comment: This isn;t working. THe value is reverting to 3.0 instead of NaN

Comment: It's not. It replaced NaNs with None, if there's a 3 it won't be replaced.

Comment: Modified the question, I am getting a weird result.

Answer (score 0):

I am using pandas == 1.3.2 version. For versions < 1.4 the above suggestions doesn't work.
This is the code that worked -

```
final_df['c'] = np.where(
                final_df["c"].isnull(),
                None,
                final_df["c"],
             )
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this code.

```
final_df = final_df.fillna(None)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).